# What does it mean to require files?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I'm trying to figure out what it means to require files, how to require files/gems/etc. I was trying to load a file in IRB, and got this piece of code (a dice generator):

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- .d6.rb
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from (irb):14
from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

- What does this code mean?
- How can I assist loading files in IRB?
- What does it mean to require files?

I assume the term "require" means to "load", but I'm at a loss as to what the mechanics are or where the files are actually located.

The file is located on my hard drive in my Ruby Projects folder:

```
C:\Ruby\d6\d6.rb
```

What I'd posted was  "irb(main):013:0> require './d6.rb'" I'm not familiar with the require_relative command (again, very new to Ruby!).  I would post the content of the file but I've been continuing to work on it and I didn't think to save a backup copy of what I'd been trying to load at the time.  I guess I shouldn't have included the .rb extension?  Ruby loads that by itself?

Also, I guess a side question would be:  after looking in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/ I don't have the "rubygems" folder or the rest of the filepath listed in the error message.  I'm assuming that's a bad thing?

Comment: Can you post the content of your file?

Comment: It looks like you did `require ".d6"` when you meant `require "./d6"`.

Comment: @Jordan Or possibly `require '.d6.rb'` instead of `require './d6'` or `require_relative 'd6'`.

Answer (score 1):

> a)what this code means,

If you mean "this error code", it is complaining that it can't find the `d6.rb` file, presumably after you did `require 'd6'`.

> b)how to assist loading files in IRB?,

Not sure what this means.

> c)what does it mean to require files? I assume the term "require" essentially just means to "load", but I'm at a loss as to what the mechanics are or where the files are actually located

Basically, yes, load - but only once. If a file has been required, you can't require it again (or more precisely you can but nothing will happen, and you get `false` instead of `true` from `require`).

As to where they are loaded from, the list of directories Ruby searches when you `require` is in `$LOAD_PATH`. When you do `require 'd6'`, only those directories are searched. When you `require './d6`, it will be loaded from the current directory. When you `require_relative 'd6'`, it will be loaded from the directory the current file is in.

EDIT: Correction thanks to Jörg W Mittag.

Comment: "When you do `require_relative 'd6'`, or `require './d6`, it will be loaded from the current directory." – No. When you do `require_relative 'd6'` it will be loaded from the directory the file which contains the call to `require_relative` is in, *not* the current directory. That's the *whole point* of `require_relative`! `require './d6` *will* load the file from the current directory … which is completely under the control of the user, and so you, as a programmer, have no way of knowing *where* that directory is and *what* file will be loaded, which is precisely the reason why `.` was removed

Comment: … from `$LOAD_PATH` and `require_relative` introduced in Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: So just out of curiousity, where is $LOAD_PATH located?  Or does it depend on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

> I assume the term "require" means to "load", but I'm at a loss as to what the mechanics are or where the files are actually located.

`require` causes the ruby parser to read and execute the file. Normaly this is used to load additional modules and classes which then could be used to extend your app code functionality.

See [Kernel#require](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require) to get more information about the load mechanics. See also [Kernel#require_relative](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative).